# Rainbow What happened to signatures in the NIST standardization process?

Tags: signature, post-quantum-cryptography, nist

The rainbow signature was not seen in round 4 of the NIST PQC standardization process. Was Rainbow not shortlisted?

Answer (score 6):

Rainbow was [catastrophically broken](https://research.ibm.com/blog/breaking-rainbow-quantum-safe), taking "a weekend on a laptop" to break.